# Eclipse is insisting that project name must be a lowercase while not letting me progress to the next step

Tags: eclipse, project, naming, conventions

[Name(MyGraphics) must start with lowercase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ybjyn.png)

["next", "finish" links are grayed out when same(myGraphics) starts with lowercase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jm0NY.png)

Comment: It is the module name that should be lower case, this is different from the project name. For a simple project you probably don't need to use the module system so jus select to not create the module-info.java

Comment: In the _New Java Project_ dialog, you have checked _Create module-info.java file_, so you get this _New module-info.java_ dialog. In the _New module-info.java_ dialog the module name is prefilled with the project name. You can use the same name for project and module, but you don't have to. Anyway, if you don't know what a `module-info.java` file is, click _Don't Create_. You can create the `module-info.java` file at a later point in time if needed. By the way, your Eclipse looks pretty outdated. Please upgrade.

Comment: Big Thanks to The very fast help that the community gave me. The suggestions given worked. I updated the eclipse version that I have and then unchecked the 'create module-info . java. Thank you everyone!